# Integrating JPA2.0 and Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, orm

last few hours I try to test with spring jpa 2.0 3.0
Finally I could recover objects persisted
but when I try to persist a new object I receive the following error message:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaAccessor.translateIfNecessary(JpaAccessor.java:152)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.flush(JpaTemplate.java:288)
>       at myPackage.testDAO.create(testDAO.java:33)
>       at myPackage.Main.main(Main.java:27)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:789)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
>       at $Proxy21.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate$8.doInJpa(JpaTemplate.java:290)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:183)
>       ... 3 more

my entity bean:

@Entity
public class Application implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Id
@Column(name="ID_APPLICATION")
private long idApplication;

@Temporal( TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="DATE_LIVRAISON")
private Date dateLivraison;

@Lob()
private String description;

@Column(name="NOM_APPLICATION")
private String nomApplication;

private String url;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Test
@OneToMany(mappedBy="application")
private List<Test> tests;

public Application() {
}

public long getIdApplication() {
    return this.idApplication;
}

public void setIdApplication(long idApplication) {
    this.idApplication = idApplication;
}

public Date getDateLivraison() {
    return this.dateLivraison;
}

public void setDateLivraison(Date dateLivraison) {
    this.dateLivraison = dateLivraison;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getNomApplication() {
    return this.nomApplication;
}

public void setNomApplication(String nomApplication) {
    this.nomApplication = nomApplication;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return this.url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public List<Test> getTests() {
    return this.tests;
}

public void setTests(List<Test> tests) {
    this.tests = tests;
}
```

}

my repository:

@Repository
public class testDAO extends JpaDaoSupport implements ItestDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

```
public List<Application> findALL() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public Application findById(long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getJpaTemplate().find(Application.class, id);
}

public void create(Application application) {
    getJpaTemplate().persist(application);
}
```

}

findById method works normally (which reassures me that jpa configuration is correct), but when I run the create method I receive the above error message.

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    testDAO dao=(testDAO)context.getBean("dao");
    Application application=new Application();
    application.setIdApplication(2);
    application.setUrl("url");
    application.setDescription("description");
    application.setNomApplication("dsdsds");
    dao.create(application);
```

any help are appreciated
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, methods of [`EntityManager`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) such as [`persist`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29), [`remove`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), [`merge`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) must be called inside a transaction, hence the error message which is actually self explaining:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Spring provides support for transaction management (see links below), including when writing tests... if you use one of the Spring testing class providing [transactional support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx).

#### See also

- [10. Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)
- [10.5 Declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)
- [10.5.6 Using `@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)